# Vertical line fitted with bracket

Tags: line, vertical

How can i write the vertical line which is fitted witch the brackets. I have a big bracket because of summation and line don't look good. I tried to use `\mid` but it also doesn't work. Sample of my code.

```
$E\left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} \E_i^{(v)} - E \left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} \E_i^{(v)}  \right] | \mathcal{F}_k \right]$
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How or where is `\E_i^{(v)}` defined?

Comment: This question is different from the supposed duplicate. This is about making a line resizing with outer brackets, and the supposed duplicate is about the reasoning behind the name “\mid”. I suggest to reopen this question.

Comment: I can't reply to this, but I would say that what you want is `\middle|`. The accepted solution is not flexible; it does not work for all sizes of brackets. My solution sets the size automatically according to the outer brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\Bigg` (or `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$E\left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} E_i^{(v)} - 
    E \left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} E_i^{(v)} 
    \right] \Bigg| \mathcal{F}_k \right]$
\end{document}
```

[image]